# Shortcut for list->stream->map()->list

Tags: java, java-stream

I often convert lists like that

```
myList.stream().map(el -> el.name).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

is there any shorter version for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you should stick to what you have already got. Why?

1. It’s already a one-liner. No real point in trying to squeeze it down further.
2. It’s idiomatic. Java developers are used to read conversions like yours, and if it’s all over the place in your code, programmers that read your code will be even more used to it. Even wrapping it in a method, like @QBrute suggested, even though a nice idea, risks harming readability because readers are not used to the wrapping method.

Remember: Brevity is not a goal. Clarity is. The two often go hand in hand, but not always, and my feeling is they may not in your case.

Reservation: My style and taste is in favour of the method reference that @Aomine uses, but it is a matter of taste. Use it if you find it clearer, not just because it’s a few chars shorter.

Comment: Definitely agree, while I do love to code-golf when possible there are times when there's no need at all and this is one of the cases. +1 for a good and useful explanation.

Answer (score 6):

There's no shorter way to do this using streams.

you could import `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;` and then use `toList` as follows to shorten the code a little bit but apart from this. The below is as compact as it gets using streams:

```
myList.stream().map(el -> el.name).collect(toList());
```

You could also use a method reference

```
myList.stream().map(T::getName).collect(toList());
```

where `T` is the name of type that contains `name` although this is not guaranteed to be shorter depending on how long the type name is but does provide better *readability* which is very important.

*Ultimately, as said this is as compact as it gets.*

Answer (score 6):

You could create a static helper method that does all the work:

```
public static <FROM, TO> List<TO> convert(List<FROM> from, Function<FROM, TO> function) {
    return from.stream().map(function).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

All you have to do is provide your list and any mapping function:

```
List<YourClass> yourList = ...;
Function<YourClass, String> func = YourClass::getName;
List<String> converted = convert(yourList, func);
```

Or even more concise:

```
List<String> converted = convert(yourList, YourClass::getName);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could statically import `Collectors.*` and then use the [`mapping(Function, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) method, like this:

```
myList.stream().collect(mapping(T::getName, toList()));
```

Where `T::getName` is a method reference and `T` is the Type of the elements in the List. Using this is more readable and also almost identical to writing: `el -> el.name`

Comment: Nice, I like it as it's imaginative and solves the question at hand +1. Although one should note that the `mapping` collector _should be_ used as a _downstream_ collector. if all you want to do is map elements then `map` should always be favoured over `mapping` collector.

Comment: @Aomine, it's actually longer than the original when you use the method reference and the static import, so I wouldn't say it really solves the question at hand, and it makes it more difficult to read…